# Stack conditions in CASE statement in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm using Oracle 10g and I'm trying to "stack" the conditions in a CASE statement, like I would do in C++ :

```
case 1:
case 2:
    // instructions
    break;
```

i.e. having the same code block executed for two different successful conditions.

I've tried :

```
WHEN 1, 2 THEN
WHEN 1 OR 2 THEN
```

... without luck.
Is it even possible ?

**EDIT** - Full snippet

```
CASE v_n
  WHEN (1 OR 2) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Case 1 or 2');
  WHEN 3 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Case 3'); 
END CASE;
```

Generates an **expression is of wrong type** error

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to use this format:

```
CASE
  WHEN v_n = 1 OR v_n = 2 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Case 1 or 2');
  WHEN v_n = 3 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Case 3'); 
END CASE;
```

Comment: `ELSE` is possible here?

Comment: Yes, you can use`ELSE`

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use IN just as in SQL:

```
BEGIN
  CASE 
    WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) IN (2015, 2016, 2017) THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('Yes');
    ELSE
      dbms_output.put_line('No');
  END CASE;
END;
/
```